# How to save or retrieve an array column using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I use `Postgres` and I have one column `ufsinss character(2)[]` like `array`. I created `userType` model to use, because I found some posts in `google` indicating the way to deal with this problem, because `Hibernate` doesn´t have native ways to deal with it.

My `userType` have this two code.

```
public static final String TYPE = "arrayStringType";

    public Class<String[]> returnedClass() {
        return String[].class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor sessionImpl, Object obj) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        Array array = rs.getArray(names[0]);
        return NullUtil.isNull(array) ? null : (String[]) array.getArray(); 
   }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor sessionImpl) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        Connection connection = st.getConnection();
        String[] stringArray = (String[]) value;
        Array array = connection.createArrayOf("character", stringArray);
        st.setArray(index, array);      
    }
```

My model entity is declared like this:

```
@Type(type = ArrayStringType.TYPE)
private String[] ufsInss;
```

But I´m getting error:

```
Mar 25, 2014 10:33:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/ecred2_manat] threw exception
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.paradigma.ecred.view.filter.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    ... [snip] ...
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.createArrayOf(Unknown Source)
    at com.paradigma.ecred.dao.hibernate.type.ArrayStringType.nullSafeSet(ArrayStringType.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:158)
    ... [snip] ...
    ... 56 more
```

> Edit 1

After change my `JDBC` version to `postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar` now I got this error when I try to get the execute the `Criteria` statement from `Hibernate`.

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Não foi possível encontrar tipo matriz para nome fornecido character.
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.createArrayOf(Unknown Source)
    at com.paradigma.ecred.dao.hibernate.type.ArrayStringType.nullSafeSet(ArrayStringType.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:158)
 ... [snip] 
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Não foi possível encontrar tipo matriz para nome fornecido character.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.createArrayOf(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:83)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.createArrayOf(Jdbc4Connection.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
    ... 100 more
```

> Edit 3

After updating my code

```
@Override
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor sessionImpl) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    Connection connection = st.getConnection();
    String[] stringArray = (String[]) value;

    if (NullUtil.isNull(stringArray)) {
        st.setNull(index, IntegerType.INSTANCE.sqlType());          
    } else {            
        Array array = connection.createArrayOf("varchar", stringArray);
        st.setArray(index, array);      
    }

}
```

I got new error

```
Mar 26, 2014 6:46:44 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl throwIt
Informações: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: ERRO: transação atual foi interrompida, comandos ignorados até o fim do bloco de transação
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3185)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3087)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3416)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1185)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1614)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    at com.paradigma.ecred.dao.impl.HibernateDAOImpl.findByFilter(HibernateDAOImpl.java:118)
    at com.paradigma.ecred.dao.impl.HibernateDAOImpl.findByFilter(HibernateDAOImpl.java:1)
    at com.paradigma.ecred.service.impl.ServiceImpl.findByFilter(ServiceImpl.java:96)
    at com.paradigma.ecred.service.impl.PropostaServiceImpl.findByFilter(PropostaServiceImpl.java:1111)
    at com.paradigma.ecred.view.LazyPojoDataModel.load(LazyPojoDataModel.java:70)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:737)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preEncode(DataTableRenderer.java:93)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:81)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1896)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.paradigma.ecred.view.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.paradigma.ecred.view.filter.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.paradigma.ecred.view.filter.IE8CompatibilityFixFilter.doFilter(IE8CompatibilityFixFilter.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
```

Above had more lines error but SO limits.

Comment: What JDBC driver version are you using? It doesn't appear to implement `createArrayOf`.

Comment: @CraigRinger I´m using `postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc3.jar`

Comment: Do you need JDBC3 for some specific reason, like a very old Java runtime?

Comment: @CraigRinger I updated my `JDBC` version to the latest and got this message error now. In portuguese `Não foi possível encontrar tipo matriz para nome fornecido character`.

Comment: Show the new exception please - edit the post and add the new exception text after the old one, along with the new driver version. Then comment here when done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had two problems:

- You were using the JDBC3 driver; and
- You were using the invalid type name `character` in your `createArrayOf` call. You must use a valid SQL type that matches how your table is defined, e.g. `varchar` or `text`.

Try:

```
Array array = connection.createArrayOf("text", stringArray);
```

(adjust depending on how you declared your array in the database).

Comment: In my first line of my post I told the type `ufsinss character(2)[]`.

Comment: @user3316847 It looks like PgJDBC can't find an array type for `character[]`, which is odd, as it works in SQL directly. Consider using `varchar` for the table definition - there's really no reason to use `character` anyway.

Comment: Try http://pastebin.org/ . In Java the most useful bits of a stack trace are often toward the end (but not at the end, that'd be too easy!).

Comment: @user3316847 The error seems pretty self explanatory. You're trying to insert `character[]` into an `integer` field. Your SQL seems plain wrong.

Comment: Loking in the javadoc I put this `   st.setNull(index, CharacterArrayType.INSTANCE.sqlType());   
` but got erros

Comment: @user3316847 If you have a new problem please post a new question. Also, "Got errors" is completely uninformative to anybody without some kind of psychic powers.

Comment: My problem is, the column has null value, if don´t have, load the array....But I still don´t know how to threat...

Comment: @DiegoMacario tried to edit with the comment *You can use in the nullSafeGet this code `array.getBaseTypeName()`; to retrieve the type of your date*, and to change `text` to `bpchar`. Edit rejected, but wanted to preserve as a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to update yout drive, because your error is about missing one class. Later you create a class to convert...

You need to make your methods as I suggested to know the type, in your case.

NullSafeGet will be like this

```
Array array = rs.getArray(names[0]);        
    return NullUtil.isNull(array) ? null : (String[]) array.getArray();
```

Using in this method, you can retrive the type of your column, as I told. But you need to insert manually data in the column to reatrive and use this code.

```
String columnType = array.getBaseTypeName();
```

So it will return `bpchar`.

And you will implement the method `nullSafeSet`.

```
Connection connection = st.getConnection();
String[] stringArray = (String[]) value;

if (NullUtil.isNull(stringArray)) {
    st.setNull(index, Types.ARRAY);
} else {            
    Array array = connection.createArrayOf("bpchar", stringArray);
    st.setArray(index, array);      
}
```

You can use this to make with other array types, but remenber to get the type of your column.